# Is there is any API to make a calendar in Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I am going to create a new appliction that will use a calendar. Do I need to use a third-party calendar, or does Android provide an API to make calendars?

Comment: i m new bee in this development so can not suggest answer at expert level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Calendar component that ships with Android. Your best bet is to create one using a GridView that you will bind to an adapter containing all the days of a given month.

Answer (score 0):

Android does have a CalendarView from 3.0 but there is no setAdapter(). You might want to either want to use a gridView and set the # of columns to 7 (note there might me a space left to the right to which you could set the padding to -1/-2). Otherwise the best is to use a ScrollView and build the grid yourself.